# How to access dynamic text on movie clip from root?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm using the same class today, based on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/countdown-in-style-with-an-airport-terminal-timer--active-4056, but when change values, if different of zero, the number does not show. How can I access `t_num` and change them from the root?

I have 16 instances: Digit0, Digit1, Digit2, etc...

Every second, I verified a value and change then (if necessary)... using this code below:

```as
if (var1!= this['digit15'].number){
  this['digit15'].flipTo(var1);
}
```

In my stage, here is the path:

```as
stage.root1.digit14.bottom2.t_num
```

Only works when var1 = 0

Comment: If 0 is the only text in your field when you compile and other values do not appear dynamically, you may need to embed the font.

Comment: Thanks you, works fine now... embed original font isn't present on system... now, works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CuddleBunny answer works fine.

> If 0 is the only text in your field when you compile and other values do not appear dynamically, you may need to embed the font. –  CuddleBunny yesterday